# How is transfer impedance of a cable different from its characterstic impedance

Tags: impedance, cables, coax, characteristic-impedance

i have been given a task to measure the impedance of a coaxial cable. i was doing some literature study and i came across two terms : transfer impedance and characterstic impedance. i am not able to understand the diference between these two terms for a cable.

Answer (score 4):

Transfer impedance:

*Transfer impedance is used to determine shield effectiveness at lower frequencies (< 1 GHz) against both ingress and egress of interfering signals.*

This is an indication of how "easy" it is for external signals (outside the cable) to couple to the signal being transported by that cable. An ideal cable would block **all signals** from the outside.

Characteristic impedance:

*The characteristic impedance or surge impedance (usually written Z0) of a uniform transmission line is the ratio of the amplitudes of voltage and current of a single wave propagating along the line; that is, a wave travelling in one direction in the absence of reflections in the other direction.*

This description is more cryptic, characteristic impedance is a property of the design of the cable. This is not an impedance you can measure with a multimeter ! You need a network analyzer or cable analyzer to measure this directly.

When transporting a (high frequency) signal through a cable you do not want to distort that signal. For this you need a cable which can handle the frequency of the signal (not attenuate it too much). Such cables have a characteristic impedance which you must use to feed the signal into the cable but also to terminate the cable with at the other end.

This is similar to how a [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) must be used. If the cable is 50 ohms it means that the impedance driving the cable must be 50 ohms and that the termination impedance at the output of the cable must also be 50 ohms. If you would use different values, the signal would reflect and distort itself.

You can also indirectly measure the characteristic impedance of an unknown cable by feeding a pulse into it while observing the voltage at the input of the cable. At the other end of the cable terminate the cable with different values like a short (zero ohm), open and 20, 40, 50 , 75 ohms etc. There will be a certain impedance where the pulse will not be reflected and that is the characteristic impedance of the cable.

Comment: There's no reason to match the source impedance of the signal driver to Zo if the load is. Unless there's a load mismatch there won't be a reflected signal to re-reflect from the source. Conversely, if the load is mismatched but the source isn't, there will be a reflection from the load but it won't re-reflect. The scheme is known as back-matching, and is useful in many situations.

Comment: @stretch *There's no reason to match the source impedance of the signal driver to Zo if the load is.* In an **ideal world** yes that is true. But the world isn't ideal so in practice everyone uses proper matching at both sides of the cable. I have never seen a practical example/product where this was not done. For the experiment with a pulse, the source matching does not matter much as we're only interested in seeing a reflection or not.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer impedance is related to the effectiveness of the shield.

> For a specified cable length, transfer impedance relates a current on
>   the surface of a shield to the voltage drop generated by this current
>   on the opposite surface of the shield. All other things being equal,
>   shields with lower DC resistance will have a lower voltage drop and
>   thus lower transfer impedance. Transfer impedance is used to determine
>   shield effectiveness at lower frequencies (< 1 GHz) against both
>   ingress and egress of interfering signals. Cable shields are normally
>   designed to reduce the transfer of interference, hence, shields with
>   lower transfer impedance are more effective than shields with higher
>   transfer impedance.

This is largely unrelated to characteristic impedance.

Quote taken from [here](http://www.araconfiber.com/what-is-transfer-impedance/)